# How to connect Azure SQL database from on-premise SSMS in hybrid environment without Azure Data Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, hybrid-cloud

I am trying to connect to Azure SQL database through on-premise SSMS and SSIS (its a requirement to push data on premise to Azure cloud). But my organization's firewall is blocking the connection to Azure database, although the Azure subscription is with same org. I tried pulling data with Azure Data Factory but it requires installation of Data Gateway and firewall is also blocking installation/registration of this gateway. Is there any alternate way to bypass this. Raising firewall exception for Data Gateway is not an option in this case. Thanks

Comment: if your org is okay to have a VPN setup between on premises and azure you can try that option. And it is a secure way too.

Comment: ExpressRoute is also an option.  However these things take time to set up so your immediate workaround is output to flat files into a share, move them to blob storage then Data Factory could take over.  Alternately the SSIS Feature Pack for 2016 has Azure Blob Source and Destination tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL works on Port 1433. You are unable to access Azure SQL probably because your organization's firewall is blocking this port. If you can get port 1433 enabled with your network admin then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Are sure your firewall blocks the installation of Data Management Gateway? I don't really know how a firewall achieves this. Maybe you meant Group Policy?

Using Data Management Gateway to move data to Azure SQL database is only requiring outgoing port 443, which is allowed by default in most firewalls.

If the Group Policy blocks installation of Data Management Gateway, you could try to upload data to a Azure Blob at first (also require outgoing port 443), and then using Data Factory to copy data from Azure Blob to Azure SQL database (gateway is not needed in that case).